# Adding values to a new column to rows that already exist - Large table

Tags: sql, database

I have a sql database on VB adding forget to add a new column before adding all the data, over 25k of rows.
Instead of me adding the forgetten data to the new column row by row, is there anyway that someone can think of by adding this new column and adding new data to the preexisting rows?

E.g.

```
ID    NAME      DATA   
1     Alpha     Cheese  
2     Bravo     Steak
3     Charlie   Wine
So on......
```

TO

```
ID    NAME      DATA    NEW COLUMN
1     Alpha     Cheese  £1.50
2     Bravo     Steak   £5.00
3     Charlie   Wine    £8.00
So on......
```

Obviously the data has to match to the correct row

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you share with us which database management system you're working on? Oracle? SQL Server? PostgreSQL? Vertica? Teradata? Other?. In all cases, you'd need a table with a new column , say `price` if it is a currency amount, and the ID of the row it needs to be added to. But a) not all databases have a `MERGE` statement, which would be the best means, and the alternative, `UPDATE` from a helper table, has different syntaxes in different DBMSs ...

Comment: How do you know what the values are?

Answer (score 0):

I read it again ; I think it's SQL Server.

In that case:

```
-- create and populate your updating table ...
CREATE TABLE newdata (
  id  INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
, pounds DECIMAL(18,2)
);
-- populate it.
INSERT INTO newdata
          SELECT 1,1.50
UNION ALL SELECT 2,5.00
UNION ALL SELECT 3,8.00
;

-- with your own table ...
-- a) modify your original table. add a currency column
ALTER TABLE thetable ADD pounds DECIMAL(18,2);

-- update the new column correctly. Use the MERGE command.
-- only a WHEN MATCHED THEN clause, as you don't add any data
MERGE INTO thetable
USING newdata
   ON thetable.id=newdata.id
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET
  pounds = newdata.pounds
;

-- effect:
SELECT * FROM thetable ORDER BY 1;
-- out Time: First fetch (1 row): 11.961 ms. All rows formatted: 11.998 ms
-- out  id |   nme   |  dat   | pounds 
-- out ----+---------+--------+--------
-- out   1 | Alpha   | Cheese |   1.50
-- out   2 | Bravo   | Steak  |   5.00
-- out   3 | Charlie | Wine   |   8.00
```